# Geographical region detection PHP

Tags: php, ip, gis

I have a website and need to display specific data to the user depending on when they are located. For example, if they are viewing my website in Leeds (UK), I need to display all Leeds related data. How do I do this in PHP? Do I need to use the visitors IP address?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You would need to work with a GeoIP database based on the user's IP address. [Maxmind has a free, less up to date version of their commercial database available](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location). From there you insert the data into your database of choice and run queries against the user's IP.

Please note that detecting IP addresses is not perfect. Someone can use a proxy server, spoof their IP, or might be working from a corporate VPN, so where they are and where their IP says they are do not always match. Be wary of this restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the [PHP Geo IP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php).

Answer (score 1):

Get the users IP and get a GEO database/API from companies like maxmind http://www.maxmind.com/. Find all sorts of useful information related to the IP, including city/location.